# Emacs org-mode: how to avoid duplicate lines in agenda, when items is scheduled AND has deadline

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Many of my TODO items in Emacs org-mode have a DEADLINE defined in the future (e. g. Friday) and are at the same time SCHEDULED today so that I already know I have to start working on this task.

Then, this task will appear twice in my agenda. That's not nice but not necessarily a problem yet, but if then

- the task has assigned a time estimate for its duration and
- I go to column view with <kbd>C-c C-x C-c</kbd> to see how much time my tasks today will need,

the **time estimate for this task is counted twice**, so e. g. if the time effort estimate is 2 hours, I'll have 4 hours in my daily agenda, as the item appears as well as scheduled today (or in the past) as also with its deadline in 3 days.

How can I avoid counting an item twice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-deadline-is-shown` can be used to hide scheduled todos in the agenda if they also have a deadline and are already displayed with the deadline.

I chose the value `Not when scheduled today` so that at least on the day the item is scheduled, I see it twice and then can delete the scheduled date.

> Documentation:
>
> Org Agenda Skip Scheduled If Deadline Is Shown
>
> Non-nil means skip scheduling line if same entry shows
>   because of deadline.
>
> In the agenda of today, an entry can
>   show up multiple times because    it is both scheduled and has a
>   nearby deadline, and maybe a plain time    stamp as well.    When this
>   variable is t, then only the deadline is shown and the fact that  the entry is scheduled today or was scheduled previously is not shown.
>   When this variable is nil, the entry will be shown several times. 
>   When    the variable is the symbol `not-today', then skip scheduled
>   previously,    but not scheduled today.

Answer (score 11):

You can set `org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled` to `t` or a small number.

> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means skip deadline prewarning when entry is also scheduled.
>
> This will apply on all days where a prewarning for the deadline would
>   be shown, but not at the day when the entry is actually due.  On that day,
>   the deadline will be shown anyway.
>
> This variable may be set to nil, t, or a number which will then give
>   the number of days before the actual deadline when the prewarnings
>   should resume.

Comment: thanks for your helpful hint. I tried it and finally decided to hide the SCHEDULED entries as soon as the deadline is shown in the agenda